# Best way to program a server status feature

Tags: java, php

Some background information.
- Running a java server on localhost
- Running a webserver on localhost

I would like a webpage to have a 'server status' feature which lets me know whether the server is running or not. My question, what is the best way to do this?

1. When I launch the java server, I write a flag in the database to signify that it is running.
2. Javascript/PHP sockets to try and bind on the same port. (Not sure if possible yet)
3. Shell script to locate the program in the task list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> When I launch the java server, I write
>   a flag in the database to signify that
>   it is running.

would not be of much help if the server should segfault.

Maybe have a look at http://mmonit.com/monit/

what is pretty much what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the simplest method is simply for your web service (backend) to try and connect to the port that your server is running on, and provide an automatically refreshing page that reports this status. If your server goes down then you'll get an faster notification than if you're polling (say) the process table.

Of course the fact that you can connect to the port doesn't really give you an indication of whether it's working other than it's opened a port (e.g. it may have no resources etc. to service requests) but it's a start.

Comment: I think your webserver should be doing this.

Comment: Well I am using PHP sockets to detect if the port is being used, thus if the server is running. But the PHP script doesn't throw an error even though the java server is running.

socket_bind($sock,$host,$port) or die("["Date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] Could not bind to socket\n");